# Both FK and primary key - Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, key, code-first, composite-primary-key

I have two tables. I would like to declare `SiteId` (along with `Username`) as the primary key.

Approaches like `[Key]` or `[Key,ForeignKey("SiteId)]` didn't work well.

```
public class SiteTable
{
    //SITE ID
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key]
    public int SiteId { get; set; }

    // NAVIGATION PROPERTY 
    public virtual ICollection<UserTable> Users { get; set; }
}

public class UserTable
{
    //USERNAME
    [Key]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    //FK
    public int SiteId { get; set; }

    //NAVIGATION PROPERTY        
    public virtual SiteTable Sites { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to define your composite key like that:

```
public class UserTable
{
   [Key,Column(Order = 0)]
   public string Username { get; set; }

   [Key,Column(Order = 1)]
   public int SiteId { get; set; }

   public virtual SiteTable Site { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I've tried this approach too, but it didn't work.
I don't know if this is a problem of the test which throws "Unavailable Db exception" or not.
Without tag on the SiteId attribute the Db is created.